# URL Rewrite Issue

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a webserver that hosts several .NET websites. The way I've set it up is so the root of the server contains a folder for each site that contains the content for it. I then have a web.config in the root directory that handles the URLs and points the user to the proper folder depending on what site they were going to.

Root directory:

- \SiteA
- \SiteB
- \web.config

And here is what the web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="SiteA" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?.siteAdomain\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\SiteA\{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="SiteB" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?.siteBdomain\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\SiteB\{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

SiteA is also using ASP.NET Membership:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/account/login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

The issue is that when I go to SiteA, authentication kicks in and I am redirected to the loginUrl. However, it is resolving the path with respect to the root folder and not the SiteA folder, which is causing a 404.

After looking into it, [this site](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms#Using_tilda) mentions this was a bug that was patched with .NET 3.5 SP1. However, my hosting service is on .NET 4.X running IIS 8.0 so I think I should be all clear of this.

Am I missing something easy here?

Comment: did  you tried: LoginURL="~/SiteA/account/login.aspx"   OR placing a new Web.Config in SiteA folder with Authentication information. ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue after consulting the following site:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx

Basically, the trick was to rewrite only URLs that did not already have the site name the subfolder in the URL:

```
<rule name="SiteA" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?.siteAdomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/SiteA/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="\SiteA\{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="SiteB" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?.siteBdomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/SiteB/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="\SiteB\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```